# Browser Runs Out of Memory After long Puppeteer Script Execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, out-of-memory, puppeteer

I've created a Puppeteer script that navigates to a website, performs searches over a range of dates, downloads PDFs, and writes certain data to a CSV file. The script is supposed to run for long periods, handling large volumes of searches and downloads. However, after around an hour of runtime, I receive a "Not enough memory to open this page" error in the browser.

My environment consists of an Azure VPS with the following specifications:

- CPU: 2.97GHz
- Virtual Processors: 16
- Memory: 64GB
- SSD: 128GB (C Drive)

The script is a Node.js code that automates the process of logging into the Tulsa County Acclaim Web portal, searching for, downloading, and recording details of public records into a CSV file, while handling downloads, pagination, and date-based incremental searches with robust error handling and stealth browsing features.

Here is my Puppeteer code:

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        // Other launch options...
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // Login and navigation logic...
    
    while (/* condition for looping over dates */) {
        // Date logic and search initiation here...
        try {
            for (let iPage = 0; /* pagination handling */) {
                // Fetching and processing data...
                // Opening new tabs and downloading PDFs...
                // Handling tab for PDF download
                // opens new page
                // May elements are listed as Table format and I click one element ad go to newTab
                let newTabPromise = new Promise((resolve) => browser.once('targetcreated', resolve));
                let newTarget = await newTabPromise;
                let newTab = await newTarget.page(); // Dereference the new target as a Page object.
                if (newTab){
                    // Sample handling for another action requiring a new tab, 'newNewTab'
                    let newNewTab = await browser.newPage();
                    if (newNewTab){
                    // Logic specific to 'newNewTab'...
                    // I could get pdf file in this newNewTab, so open newNewTab and download pdf file
                    await newNewTab.close();
                    }
                    await newTab.close();
                }                
                    
            }
               
            // Data processing and CSV writing after closing tabs to conserve memory...

            } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
        // Increment date logic...
    }

    // Consider adding browser.close() here to ensure the browser closes when the loop is complete.
})();
```

Reference this full code: https://github.com/flurryunicorn/county-lib-scraper/tree/main/tulsa_county

I suspect the memory issue might be related to opening and closing many tabs or perhaps some uncollected garbage in the Puppeteer/Node.js environment. Could the way I'm handling the downloads or the constant opening and closing of tabs be leading to the memory leak?

Is there any practice or Puppeteer setting recommended for long-running tasks like this to avoid memory leaks or any specific parts of my approach I should reconsider?

Comment: There's a lot of code here. I suggest minimizing it to isolate the leak. See [mcve] for strategies. If the browser runs out of memory, that's different than Node running out of memory. Opening/closing tabs shouldn't matter--if anything, it helps with memory since if there's a leak on a page it's destroyed. If you close every page after a few operations, you should be good both in terms of the browser tab's memory as well as Node's memory. It's unlikely that Puppeteer has memory leaks, but it's possible that the website does, if it's not prepared to be automated aggressively.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my code. For explaining my script, I open new tab and open newNewTab again in a new tab, I download from newNewTab and close newNewTab, also scrap information from newTab and close this newTab. And I loop. As you could check, the resource of the vps is enough big, is looping open new tabs could occur this kind of problem?

Comment: Same response as above. If the tabs are closed I don't see how they'll leak. If you're printing `console.log((await browser.pages()).length)` and the number isn't growing, then you should be good as far as a Node leak goes, assuming you're not accumulating event listeners (you're using `page.once()` so that seems OK on an eyeball). As mentioned above, it's important to establish whether it's the website tab crashing because it's out of memory running the webpage, or if it's Node crashing because it's out of memory running your Puppeteer code. Sounds like it's the former.

Comment: If sometims the tab is destroyed, so next function is not calling for a long time, then it could occur the browser memory leak problems?

Answer (score 0):

This should be related to Chrome itself, I have tested similar thing, and it doesn't matter if you open/close pages/tabs or just looping in one tab, memory usage still gradually rises.

On top of all this, I guess there are some memory limitations on Azure, even though specifications are highend.